# Is it possible to deploy a pre-trained CNN model into TWO different devices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As a part of my research work, I am in need to run a pre-trained CNN model in two devices, one in a smartphone and one in a server PC.

To undertake a feasibility study on this, I created a CNN model with 7 layers using MNIST dataset in order to detect the hand written numbering image. Then, I created two separate models based on this CNN model. I named those models as CNN-A and CNN-B.

**Original CNN model = CNN-A model + CNN-B model**

I implemented the above models in my PC using Python and TensorFlow as sw platforms. During the prediction, the raw input dataset are received by CNN-A. The output of the CNN-A are used as input to the CNN-B.

However, I implemented the above prediction in a single device- in my laptop. For my research, I have to deploy the original CNN model into two separated devices to make such a prediction task.

Therefore, Now I am currently searching a way to deploy the CNN-A in a smartphone and CNN-B in a server pc to run the original pre-trained CNN mode in two different devices as a distributed way.

Is it possible to run a single CNN model on Two different devices? Does anybody have any idea on this distributed deployment, please?

Comment: What is your purpose of running the model on two devices? If it is for learning, are you familiar with federated learning?

Comment: Thank your for your response, Kaveh. To run a pre-trained CNN model,  it require more computational power and memory. This is problem for low power devices such as smartphone. In order to reduce it, I am trying to run the pretrained CNN model in a smartphone and PC. That is, a part of inference is in smart phone and another part of inference will be in server pc. This kind of setup may reduce computational workload for the CNN inference on smart phone.

Comment: If it was for learning you could use ``MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy``. But if it is just taking inference from a model, let's say A that is running on device A and feed it's output to the input of model B which is running on device B, and then get the output of model B, I think you can implement services using tools like ``TFServing``. However let other people may have a better solution for this.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to give more details on how to use TFServing to the above problem?